# Sending Emails with Symfony Mailer

Tags: php, email, mailer, symfony5.4

I have fresh installation of Symfony 5.4. I have followed the documentation in order to send email from my own smtp server but couldn't make it work. So, I'm trying https://mailtrap.io/ with the following configurations with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

###### Steps followed

`composer require symfony/mailer`
`composer require symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle`

`MAILER_DSN=smtp://d62b667a28d6af:023c577a51bb51@smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 #MAILER_DSN=smtp://d62b667a28d6af:023c577a51bb51@smtp.mailtrap.io:2525?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login`

**RegistrationController**

```
       ...

        // generate a signed url and email it to the user
        $this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
            (new TemplatedEmail())
                ->from(new Address('registration@my_host.com', 'Registration Confirmation'))
                ->to($user->getEmail())
                ->subject('Please Confirm your Email')
                ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
        );
```

mailer.yml

```
framework:
    mailer:
        dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
```

Answer (score 3):

run composer require symfony/messenger
then
run php bin/console messenger:consume async

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Symfony with the --docker option, then your docker-compose.override.yml file will contain a configuration for a mail catcher when you add symfony mailer.

From the official Symfony website: https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/3-zero.html

--docker: On your local machine, we will use Docker to manage services like PostgreSQL. This option enables Docker so that Symfony will automatically add Docker services based on the required packages (a PostgreSQL service when adding the ORM or a mail catcher when adding Symfony Mailer for instance).

In your [Profiler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html) bar, hover over "Server" to reveal an array of options one of which is Webmail. Your webmail will be getting delivered there if the configuration described above exists in your project.

Answer (score 0):

run composer require symfony/messenger then run php bin/console messenger:consume async